# Ionic4 build android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, build, ionic4

I would like build my ionic app for android but i have an error.

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\masmas\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (DEPRECATED)
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android --release exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: Did you try to add ANDROID_SDK_ROOT in bash variable? Did you have the Androidstudio installed? It seems is missing the gradle too.

Comment: I have installe android studio .                                                          
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\maceo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 13.0.2
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install Gradle manually, as latest versions of android studio is not supporting the gradle build from external sources.To install gradle:- https://gradle.org/install/.